# Can I use a Proc step within another proc step?

Tags: sas, sas-macro, sas-iml

I am writing an `nlmixed` procedure, and for the *likelihood function*, I want to use values generated with the `iml` procedure. So I am wondering if there is a way of using `proc iml` inside a `proc nlmixed`.

```
proc nlmixed data = xxx;
  parms b0=0 b1=0;
  mu = exp(b0 + b1*Age);
  ll = log(((mu**y)*exp(-mu))/gamma(y+1));
  model y~ general(ll);
run;

proc iml;
  v = {5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14};
  z = j(10,1,.);
  do i = 1 to 6;
    z[i] = ((v[i]-5)/5)*((mu**v[i])*exp(-mu))/gamma(v[i]+1);
  end;
  ll=log(sum(z));
quit;
```

The idea is to:

- use *mu* from `nlmixed` inside the `proc iml`
- but the *ll* from both steps should be inside `nlmixed`

Comment: You may want to be a lot more clear in your question.  "first proc step" "second proc step" aren't clear (do you mean first is NLMIXED and second the IML step? Then call them that), and how are you actually getting NLMIXED to use this calculated LL value (i.e., let's say you rewrote your NLMIXED to use the LL calculated in IML, handwave away the actually running IML inside it, how would your new NLMIXED look like?)

Comment: Also - have you considered doing the whole thing in IML?  See for example [this blog post](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2011/10/12/maximum-likelihood-estimation-in-sasiml.html)?

Comment: I rephrased a little bit your question, and there's a point that I think needs to be clarified: "the ll from both steps should be inside nlmixed". If I understand correctly, you want to calculate `ll` with `proc iml`. If this is the case, why do you _also_ calculate it in `proc nlmixed`?